# Creating meta tags for Linkedin - Publish Date "not found"

Tags: linkedin-api, blogs, facebook-opengraph

I *was* using the following tags in relation to the posted date of a website (blog) article:

```
<meta name="article-published_time" property="article:published_time" content="2019-10-21T00:00:00-0600">
<meta name="article-modified_time" property="article:modified_time" content="2019-10-22T13:47:16-0600">
```

The [linked in post inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) *near the bottom* the section labeled

> Metadata that we gathered about this page:

was providing the following feedback:

[image: Publish date - No publication date found]

So then I added *this* tag:

```
<meta name="publish_date" property="og:publish_date" content="2019-10-21T00:00:00-0600">
```

Immediately, the post-inspector responded with:

[image: Publish date - 10/20/2019, 7:00:00 PM]

---

BUT, when I removed that final tag, the post-inspector still showed the  publish date.  Logic would say that if that was the *only tag* that caused the publish date to be found, removing that final tag should make it go away.  But removing it does not make it go away.

The question is - which of these tags or combination of these tags is required for LinkedIn to show the publish date (added value if you also answer the question as it pertains to Facebook).

Comment: Annoying that LinkedIn provide "How to change" information embedded in to that interface for _Description_ and _Author_ but not for _Publish date_. It's astonishing how this stuff has to appear like black magic - Facebook and Twitter are definitely trumping LinkedIn when it comes to clarity of information out in the public domain.

Comment: What strikes me https://ogp.me/ - property="og:publish_date" - does not exist in the og docs

Comment: thanks for discovering this trick, now (sep 2020) it's not working though, I tried the last, the last and the first, all of three. This is what is rendered: <meta data-n-head="ssr" name="article-modified_time" property="article:modified_time" content="2020-01-09T00:00:00-0600">, maybe the data-n-head messes with linkedin, who knows.

Comment: Where am I wrong??? https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fsitedev.rouse.com%2Ftestseo

Comment: When you read the introduction page of the post inspector, it says "... you can see when we last updated our data on it...". So I assume this date comes from their internal scraping process :-|

Comment: @BartJolling i was testing on or around `2019-10-22T13:47:16-0600` but the inspector picked up the datetime of `2019-10-21T00:00:00-0600` which would not support that theory.

Answer (score -1):

Programmatically setting a DateTime like `2019-10-21T00:00:00-0600` means a date and time format string like this: `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"`

C# example:

```
<meta name="publish_date" property="og:publish_date" content="@post.Published.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")">
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: good info but not answering the question ~