# No publication date found Linkedin POST INSPECTOR

Tags: html, seo, linkedin-api, meta-tags

It took me more than a month to find the cause of not finding the **publication date.**
[image]

Here my code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Rouse - Rouse launches China Software Litigation Report</title>

<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <meta name="title" content="Rouse launches China Software Litigation Report">
    <meta property='og:title' content='Rouse launches China Software Litigation Report'/>
    <meta property='og:image' content='https://sitedev.rouse.com/media/hqphzwt4/data-abstract.jpg?anchor=center&amp;mode=crop&amp;width=1903&amp;height=713&amp;rnd=132415927615200000'/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="article">
        <meta property='og:description' content='Report examines how foreign companies have fared in Chinese courts'/>
        <meta property='og:url' content='/insights/news/2020/rouse-launches-china-software-litigation-report'/>
        <meta name="article-published_time" property="article:published_time" content="2019-10-21T00:00:00-0600">
        <meta name="article-modified_time" property="article:modified_time" content="2019-10-22T13:47:16-0600">
        <meta name="publish_date" property="og:publish_date" content="2019-10-21T00:00:00-0600">  
        <meta name="author" content="Chris Bailey, Doug Clark, Nandi (Landy) Jiang"/>
        <meta name="generator" content="Chris Bailey, Doug Clark, Nandi (Landy) Jiang" />
```

I have referenced at this link [Creating meta tags for Linkedin - Publish Date "not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58511410/creating-meta-tags-for-linkedin-publish-date-not-found) but it not working.

> And I asked the facilitator but the answer was up on the stackoverflow to ask the geeks

---

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58511410/creating-meta-tags-for-linkedin-publish-date-not-found/75712622 but doesn't have an accepted answer so it can't be flagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by adding a [time element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) to the page:

`<time datetime="2021-05-23">May 2021</time>`

Comment: This fix didn't work for me.